# Why can't I add OnAppointmentDataBound property to my RadScheduler on my .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, databound, radscheduler

I am attempting to add an OnAppointmentDataBound property to my RadScheduler control on an aspx page using ASP.NET web forms and create a corresponding method in the code behind page that will update background colors for the control.

This is what my control looks like on the aspx page:

```
 <telerik:RadScheduler ID="rscCompliance" runat="server" RowHeight="17px" Width="480px" Height="350px" 
                ReadOnly="true" SelectedView="MonthView" DataKeyField="CaseId" DataSubjectField="Compliance" 
                DataStartField="WeekBeginningDate" DataEndField="WeekEndDate" AutoPostBack="false" OnAppointmentDataBound="rscCompliance_AppointmentDataBound" >
                <AdvancedForm Modal="true" />
                <TimelineView UserSelectable="false" />
                <AgendaView UserSelectable="false" />
                <TimeSlotContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="false" />
                <AppointmentContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="false" />
                <Reminders Enabled="false" />
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
```

In the code behind:

```
private void rscCompliance_AppointmentDataBound(object sender, SchedulerEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Appointment.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
```

I get the following compilation error:

"Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.pages_adaptivereconditioning_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'rscCompliance_AppointmentDataBound' and no extension method 'rscCompliance_AppointmentDataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pages_adaptivereconditioning_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Im not sure what directive or assembly reference I would need to add because I already have added the necessary Telerik references. I'm not sure what else I could be missing?

Thanks.